# JPA Hibernate Find by ID & Version

Tags: hibernate, jpa

The find method in JPA only accepts primary key, is there a way to include the Version property to find the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to use the version property to find an entity? If you're using a surrogate primary key field (as recommended by Hibernate) you should be able to identify a row by the id alone.

The Version field is used by hibernate to ensure that a loaded entity is not changed between loading and persisting.

If you really wanted to use the id and version you would need a query:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("select from MyTable where id = ? and version =?");
    query.setParameter(0, myId);
    query.setParameter(1, myVersion);
    query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I agree on the surrogate key; but I have a requirement to validate the version of an object before merging with the existing entity in the database. The idea was to query the database with the Id & Version there by avoiding the manual version check. The approach that you have suggested might work but I am looking for a generic approach as the Id columns in all my entities have different names.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the entity with the id and then get the version from it in order to confirm the version before the merge? There is nothing to be gained by using the id and version since a row only has a single version which isn't part of the key right?

Comment: the approach you suggested earlier with the query solved my problem and I was able to query using both entity & version. Even though the entities use a different naming conventions for identifiers I could use id and hibernate while generating the sql replaced the id with the corresponding identifier name.

Comment: Haha! Yes you're right. I'd forgotten about that. We actually regard that feature as a bug. Since we always have a primary key called id on our tables which may not be the @Id. Developers sometimes attempt to select * from blah where id = ? and don't get the result they expect because hibernate uses the @Id in place of the id column on the table.